# Python Guizero -- how to increment 1 on counter variables only after exiting app?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, voting-system, guizero

I am having a problem with adding votes or incrementing 1 vote to counter variables only after the app is exited using the X in the top right hand corner of the window. Is there a way to do this either making the variables "counter" [1 through 6] GLOBAL or coding other variables to assign the totals of all the votes for those specific candidates added or created by my previous app?

I'm trying to create a login system that logs/stores each voter [csv files or database] after form fill out then allows voting, both placed on loop so after voting it goes back to login window but validates not allowing same info to vote again. after voting_card.py exits it will write total tallies into a results file that can be viewed as a gui written window.

I've tried global or $ variables but received errors and unexpected results.

ballot_build.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#imports ------------------
from guizero import App, Box, Text, TextBox, TitleBox, ListBox, ButtonGroup, Combo, PushButton, Window
#app---------------------------
app = App(title="Ballot Builder")
app.bg = "white"

#functions--------------------------------------------------------------------------
def add_entry():
    if choice.value == "Presidential" and combo.value == "Independent/3rdParty":
        listbox5.append(name_input.value)
    elif choice.value == "Presidential" and combo.value == "Republican":
        listbox1.append(name_input.value)
    elif choice.value == "Presidential" and combo.value == "Democrat":
        listbox2.append(name_input.value)
    elif choice.value == "Vice-Presidential" and combo.value == "Independent/3rdParty":
        listbox6.append(name_input.value)
    elif choice.value == "Vice-Presidential" and combo.value == "Republican":
        listbox3.append(name_input.value)
    elif choice.value == "Vice-Presidential" and combo.value == "Democrat":
        listbox4.append(name_input.value)

def del_entry():
    if choice.value == "Presidential" and combo.value == "Independent/3rdParty":
        listbox5.remove(name_input.value)
    elif choice.value == "Presidential" and combo.value == "Republican":
        listbox1.remove(name_input.value)
    elif choice.value == "Presidential" and combo.value == "Democrat":
        listbox2.remove(name_input.value)
    elif choice.value == "Vice-Presidential" and combo.value == "Independent/3rdParty":
        listbox6.remove(name_input.value)
    elif choice.value == "Vice-Presidential" and combo.value == "Republican":
        listbox3.remove(name_input.value)
    elif choice.value == "Vice-Presidential" and combo.value == "Democrat":
        listbox4.remove(name_input.value)
        
def save_ballot():
    fileHandle = open('.ballot', 'w')
    fileHandle.write(label2.value + "\n" + label4.value + "\n" + str(listbox1.items) + "\n" + label8.value + "\n" + str(listbox5.items) + "\n" + label5.value + "\n" + str(listbox2.items) + "\n" + label3.value + "\n" + label6.value + "\n" + str(listbox3.items) + "\n" + label9.value + "\n" + str(listbox6.items) + "\n" + label7.value + "\n" + str(listbox4.items) + "\n")
    ballot = Window(app)
    choices1 = ButtonGroup(ballot, options=[])
    choices2 = ButtonGroup(ballot, options=[])
    for item in listbox1.items[1:]:
        name = item
        choices1.append(str(name))
    for item in listbox5.items[1:]:
        name = item
        choices1.append(str(name))
    for item in listbox2.items[1:]:
        name = item
        choices1.append(str(name))
    for item in listbox3.items[1:]:
        name = item
        choices2.append(str(name))
    for item in listbox6.items[1:]:
        name = item
        choices2.append(str(name))
    for item in listbox4.items[1:]:
        name = item
        choices2.append(str(name))
    #fileHandle.close()
    #app.destroy()

def close_app():
    app.destroy()
    
#widgets-----------------------------------
label1 = Text(app, text="Candidates:")
label1.text_size = 20
label1.font = "Times New Roman"

box1 = Box(app)

box2 = Box(box1, align="top")
label2 = Text(box2, text="Presidential:")
label2.text_size = 16
label2.text_color = "gold"

box4 = Box(box2, layout="grid", align="left")
label4 = Text(box4, text="Republican:", grid=[0,0])
label4.text_color = "red"
titlebox1 = TitleBox(box4, "List", grid=[0,1])
listbox1 = ListBox(titlebox1, items=[""], scrollbar=True)

label8 = Text(box4, text="Independent/other:", grid=[1,0])
label8.text_color = "green"
titlebox5 = TitleBox(box4, "List", grid=[1,1])
listbox5 = ListBox(titlebox5, items=[""], scrollbar=True)

label5 = Text(box4, text="Democrat:", grid=[2,0])
label5.text_color = "blue"
titlebox2 = TitleBox(box4, "List", grid=[2,1])
listbox2 = ListBox(titlebox2, items=[""], scrollbar=True)

#buttons_and_Input------------------------------------
box5 = Box(box2, layout="grid", align="right")
choice = ButtonGroup(box5, options=["Presidential", "Vice-Presidential"], selected="Presidential", grid=[0,0])
combo = Combo(box5, options=["Republican", "Independent/3rdParty", "Democrat"], selected="Independent/3rdParty", grid=[0,1])
name_input = TextBox(box5, text="Type NAME here", grid=[0,2], width=20)
button1 = PushButton(box5, text="Add +", grid=[0,3], align="left", command=add_entry)
button2 = PushButton(box5, text="Delete", grid=[0,3], align="right", command=del_entry)

#backToAssignment------------------------------------
box3 = Box(box1, align="bottom")
label3 = Text(box3, text="Vice-Presidential:")
label3.text_size = 16
label3.text_color = "silver"

box6 = Box(box3, layout="grid", align="left")
label6 = Text(box6, text="Republican:", grid=[0,0])
label6.text_color = "red"
titlebox3 = TitleBox(box6, "List", grid=[0,1])
listbox3 = ListBox(titlebox3, items=[""], scrollbar=True)

label9 = Text(box6, text="Independent/other:", grid=[1,0])
label9.text_color = "green"
titlebox6 = TitleBox(box6, "List", grid=[1,1])
listbox6 = ListBox(titlebox6, items=[""], scrollbar=True)

label7 = Text(box6, text="Democrat:", grid=[2,0])
label7.text_color = "blue"
titlebox4 = TitleBox(box6, "List", grid=[2,1])
listbox4 = ListBox(titlebox4, items=[""], scrollbar=True)

#buttonsAndSaveInput----------------------------------------
box7 = Box(box3, align="right")
button3 = PushButton(box7, text="Save", align="left", command=save_ballot)
button4 = PushButton(box7, text="Cancel", align="right", command=close_app)

#display-----------
app.display()
```

voting_card.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#imports ------------------
from guizero import App, Box, Text, TitleBox, ButtonGroup, Combo, PushButton, Window, TextBox
import string
from string import *
import csv 

#csv file setup-----------
# field names 
fields = ['Name', 'SSN', 'DLN']
# name of csv file 
with open(".voter_records.csv", 'w') as csvfile:
    # creating a csv writer object 
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile) 
    # writing the fields 
    csvwriter.writerow(fields) 
                    
#count variables for ButtonGroup-choices------------
count1 = 0
count2 = 0
count3 = 0
count4 = 0
count5 = 0
count6 = 0
#functions---------------------------------------
#reOpen the Login Window and clear the inputs
def open_login():
    window.show(wait=True)
    name_input.value="Type NAME here"
    SSN_input1.value="###"
    SSN_input2.value="##"
    SSN_input3.value="####"
    DrvLic_input.value="Type DL# here"
#Log voters---------------------------------------
def close_login():
    SSN = str(SSN_input1.value) + str(SSN_input2.value) + str(SSN_input3.value)
    # data rows of csv file 
    rows = [[name_input.value, SSN, DrvLic_input.value]]
    if len(SSN) == 0 and (len(DrvLic_input.value) == 0 or DrvLic_input.value == "Type DL# here"):
        window.warn("No SSN# or DL#!", "You must put in either\n your Social Security Number\n OR your Driver's License Number!")
        if len(SSN) != 9:
            window.warn("SSN# not right number!", "Either your Social Security Number\n has too many characters\n or not enough characters!")
        elif len(DrvLic_input.value) < 7:
            window.warn("DL# Too Short!", "Your Driver's License Number\n can not be shorter\n than 7 characters!")
    else:
        # writing to csv file 
        with open(".voter_records.csv", 'a') as csvfile: 
            # creating a csv writer object 
            csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile) 
                
            # writing the data rows 
            csvwriter.writerows(rows)
        window.hide()
        choices1.value = ""
        choices2.value = ""
        choices3.value = ""
        choices4.value = ""
        choices5.value = ""
        choices6.value = ""

def close_app():
    open_login()
    
def submit_vote():
    #Each Count-Variable made "Global" for each conditionl choice to Increment------------
    global count1
    global count2
    global count3
    global count4
    global count5
    global count6
    #Prevents Prez multi-vote error-----------
    if choices1.value and choices2.value:
        app.warn("Oops!", "You have selected more than 1 Presidential Candidate, try again.")
        choices1.value = ""
        choices2.value = ""
        choices3.value = ""
    elif choices2.value and choices3.value:
        app.warn("Oops!", "You have selected more than 1 Presidential Candidate, try again.")
        choices1.value = ""
        choices2.value = ""
        choices3.value = ""
    elif choices1.value and choices3.value:
        app.warn("Oops!", "You have selected more than 1 Presidential Candidate, try again.")
        choices1.value = ""
        choices2.value = ""
        choices3.value = ""
    #Prevents VP multi-vote error----------------
    if choices4.value and choices5.value:
        app.warn("Oops!", "You have selected more than 1 VICE-Presidential Candidate, try again.")
        choices4.value = ""
        choices5.value = ""
        choices6.value = ""
    elif choices5.value and choices6.value:
        app.warn("Oops!", "You have selected more than 1 VICE-Presidential Candidate, try again.")
        choices4.value = ""
        choices5.value = ""
        choices6.value = ""
    elif choices4.value and choices6.value:
        app.warn("Oops!", "You have selected more than 1 VICE-Presidential Candidate, try again.")
        choices4.value = ""
        choices5.value = ""
        choices6.value = ""
        
    #writes Prez choice selection to text file with increment vote count-------     
    fileHandle = open('.results', 'a')
    if choices1.value:
        #Incrementals for each count of choices group by value's text------------
        count1 += 1
        fileHandle.write(choices1.value_text +" = "+ str(count1) +"\n")
    elif choices2.value:
        count2 += 1
        fileHandle.write(choices2.value_text +" = "+ str(count2) +"\n")
    elif choices3.value:
        count3 += 1
        fileHandle.write(choices3.value_text +" = "+ str(count3) +"\n")
    #writes VP choice selection to text file with increment vote count-------   
    if choices4.value:
        count4 += 1
        fileHandle.write(choices4.value_text +" = "+ str(count4) +"\n")
    elif choices5.value:
        count5 += 1
        fileHandle.write(choices5.value_text +" = "+ str(count5) +"\n")
    elif choices6.value:
        count6 += 1
        fileHandle.write(choices6.value_text +" = "+ str(count6) +"\n")
    open_login()
    
def save_when_closed():
    #Then write it as string to file!-----------
    if app.yesno("Save", "Do you want to save?"):
        app.destroy()
        
    
#app---------------------------
app = App(title="Ballot", layout="grid")
app.bg = "white"

box1 = Box(app, grid=[0,0])
label1 = Text(box1, text="Presidential Candidates:", color="gold")
titlebox1 = TitleBox(box1, "President")
label3 = Text(titlebox1, text="Republicans:")
label3.bg = "red"
choices1 = ButtonGroup(titlebox1, options=[], selected="")
label4 = Text(titlebox1, text="Independent/3rd Party:")
label4.bg = "green"
choices2 = ButtonGroup(titlebox1, options=[], selected="")
label5 = Text(titlebox1, text="Democrats:")
label5.bg = "blue"
choices3 = ButtonGroup(titlebox1, options=[], selected="")

box2 = Box(app, layout="grid", grid=[1,0])
label2 = Text(box2, text="Vice-Presidential Candidates:", color="silver", grid=[0,0])
titlebox2 = TitleBox(box2, "Vice-President", layout="grid", grid=[0,1])
label6 = Text(titlebox2, text="Republicans:", grid=[0,0])
label6.bg = "red"
choices4 = ButtonGroup(titlebox2, options=[], selected="", grid=[0,1])
label7 = Text(titlebox2, text="Independent/3rd Party:", grid=[0,2])
label7.bg = "green"
choices5 = ButtonGroup(titlebox2, options=[], selected="", grid=[0,3])
label8 = Text(titlebox2, text="Democrats:", grid=[0,4])
label8.bg = "blue"
choices6 = ButtonGroup(titlebox2, options=[], selected="", grid=[0,5])

box3 = Box(box2, layout="grid", grid=[0,2])
button1 = PushButton(box3, text='Submit', command=submit_vote, grid=[0,0])
button2 = PushButton(box3, text='Cancel', command=close_app, grid=[1,0])

with open('.ballot', 'r') as fh:
    specific_lines1 = [2]
    for pos, l_num in enumerate(fh):
        if pos in specific_lines1:
            for a in l_num.split(","):
                if a != "[\'\'":
                    if a.rfind(']') != -1:
                        choices1.append(a[0:-2])
                        choices1.remove("[\'\'")
                    else:
                        choices1.append(a)
with open('.ballot', 'r') as fh:
    specific_lines2 = [4]
    for pos, l_num in enumerate(fh):
        if pos in specific_lines2:
            for b in l_num.split(","):
                if b != "[\'\'":
                    if b.rfind(']') != -1:
                        choices2.append(b[0:-2])
                        choices2.remove("[\'\'")
                    else:
                        choices2.append(b)
with open('.ballot', 'r') as fh:
    specific_lines3 = [6]
    for pos, l_num in enumerate(fh):
        if pos in specific_lines3:
            for c in l_num.split(","):
                if c != "[\'\'":
                    if c.rfind(']') != -1:
                        choices3.append(c[0:-2])
                        choices3.remove("[\'\'")
                    else:
                        choices3.append(c)
with open('.ballot', 'r') as fh:
    specific_lines4 = [9]
    for pos, l_num in enumerate(fh):
        if pos in specific_lines4:
            for d in l_num.split(","):
                if d != "[\'\'":
                    if d.rfind(']') != -1:
                        choices4.append(d[0:-2])
                        choices4.remove("[\'\'")
                    else:
                        choices4.append(d)
with open('.ballot', 'r') as fh:
    specific_lines5 = [11]
    for pos, l_num in enumerate(fh):
        if pos in specific_lines5:
            for e in l_num.split(","):
                if e != "[\'\'":
                    if e.rfind(']') != -1:
                        choices5.append(e[0:-2])
                        choices5.remove("[\'\'")
                    else:
                        choices5.append(e)
with open('.ballot', 'r') as fh:
    specific_lines6 = [13]
    for pos, l_num in enumerate(fh):
        if pos in specific_lines6:
            for f in l_num.split(","):
                if f != "[\'\'":
                    if f.rfind(']') != -1:
                        choices6.append(f[0:-2])
                        choices6.remove("[\'\'")
                    else:
                        choices6.append(f)
#LoginWindow design-------------------------
window = Window(app, "Voter Login")
box4 = Box(window, layout="grid")
nameLabel = Text(box4, text="Your Name:", grid=[0,0], align='left')
name_input = TextBox(box4, text="Type NAME here", width=20, grid=[0,1], align='left')
box5 = Box(box4, layout="grid", grid=[0,2])
infoLabel = Text(box5, text="Input Your\n Social Security\n Number\n or your Driver's\n License Number!:", grid=[0,0])
box6 = Box(box5, layout="grid", grid=[1,0], align='right')
SSN_input1 = TextBox(box6, text="###", width=3, grid=[0,0], align='right', hide_text=True)
SSN_input2 = TextBox(box6, text="##", width=2, grid=[1,0], hide_text=True)
SSN_input3 = TextBox(box6, text="####", width=4, grid=[2,0], align='left')
DivLabel = Text(box6, text="/OR:", grid=[1,1])
DrvLic_input = TextBox(box6, text="Type DL# here", width=14, grid=[2,2])
button3 = PushButton(box4, text='VOTE!', command=close_login, grid=[0,3])

app.when_closed = save_when_closed

app.display()
```